# Why is this external MP4 video not showing in Chrome in my HTML?

Tags: html, video

I have a Django project, in which I want to display videos in my webpage, as reports. The videos are hosted on another server which we use in my office, and are saved when a user sends them through Whatsapp. After being saved, the other server sends my server the information, such as the URL of the video.

When I try to display the video in my view, I use this code:

```
<video width="100%" height="400" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="{{ video }}" />
</video>
```

Where `video` is the full URL. The video displays properly on Firefox, but on Chrome, just the video player displays, but the video never loads.

The videos will be coming from the users, and transformed to MP4 in the other server, so I really can't be transforming the videos to other formats, and I cannot know which web browsers will the clients be using, so I'd like to know which is a generic way in which I can reliably display an MP4 video on a Chrome browser.

Comment: Show the video url here. Without the url, how can we know what wrong with the video.

Comment: The URL is this: http://207.244.254.64/1595373907_5214921055833.mp4

Comment: @IvánFloresVázquez you need to upload the MP4 file for us to test in Chrome ourselves and check for codec issues. I think your shown link points to your local server? Or at least download & check the video with **MediaInfo** for telling us the codec settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that, for Chrome, there's a problem when the site is in HTTPS and the server which had the videos was in HTTP. A co-worker changed the domain and is working properly now.